# php file get contents not working while fetching fb page data

Tags: php, json, facebook, facebook-graph-api, file-get-contents

I have the following code to get fb page list

```
    $graph_url_pages = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?access_token=".$_SESSION['token'];
    $pagedata=file_get_contents($graph_url_pages);
    echo "DATA : <br>";
    print_r($pagedata);
    $pages=json_decode($pagedata,true);
    var_dump($pages);
    $dropdown = "";
    for($i=0;$i<count($pages->data);$i++)
    {
        if($me=="iamindex"){
           $dropdown .= "<option value='".$pages->data[$i]->access_token."-".$pages->data[$i]->id."'>".$pages->data[$i]->name."</option>";
        }elseif($me=="iammulti"){
            $dropdown .= "<input type='checkbox' name='page' id='status' value='".$pages->data[$i]->access_token."-".$pages->data[$i]->id."'>".$pages->data[$i]->name."<br>";
        }else{$dropdown.="<option value=''>No Category Selection</option>";}

    }
```

**$pagedata** and **$pages** is empty and so dropdown doesn't get populated.

Somewhere at the top of the page I am using `Ob_start()` and at the end `Ob_flush();` And they are needed. I don't know whether this is the issue.

Would be great if somebody can point out what is going wrong ! if more code is needed, I can provide. Please note I am an amateur programmer. Self taught.

Comment: Try using curl, so you can get the error code that Facebook is potentially returning. Or, safe mode in php might be on, or stream wrappers might be disabled. Check in php.ini

Comment: You echoing or printing before file_get_contents?

Comment: may be allow_url_fopen=0 in your php.ini file due to some security purpose try to use curl

Comment: are you sure your access token is a valid user access token that includes the manage_pages permission? btw, definitely use curl.

Comment: Hi i am getting the following message when I used curl method usggested by JYoThl   --     {"error":{"message":"API calls from the server require an appsecret_proof argument","type":"GraphMethodException","code":100,"fbtrace_id":"F0C3Ly6IpJN"}}

Comment: Shadab, I was echoing after file_get_contents

Comment: I got what that means. I needed to switch off Require App Secret in the facebook advanced settings. Now all is well. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using cURL

```
  $graph_url_pages = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?access_token=".$_SESSION['token'];

  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $graph_url_pages);

  if(curl_error($c))
  {
     echo 'error:' . curl_error($c);
     //it will produce the error if any exists 
  } 

  $data = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
  print_r($data);
```

Comment: I am getting the following message when I use the Curl above. But its Greek and Latin to me :(    {"error":{"message":"API calls from the server require an appsecret_proof argument","type":"GraphMethodException","code":100,"fbtrace_id":"F0C3Ly6IpJN"}}

Comment: I got what that means. I needed to switch off Require App Secret in the facebook advanced settings. Now all is well. Thank you :)